# How to create a radio button with text at left of button programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I have created my radio buttons with text at left of its button in xml :

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_sattelite1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:text="@string/sattelite1" />
```

For some reason I have to create some of them in my java code but I'm unable to design it as above.

EDIT:
with the help of my friends @Hariharan and @Haresh  I end up with this code :

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 57, 72);
radioButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
```

But now the problem is that both buttons at left and right appears.

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

```
yourradiobutton.setCompoundDrawables(drawable_left, drawable_top, drawable_right, drawable_bottom);
```

**EDIT**

```
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    radioButton.setText("sattelite1");
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 57, 72);
    radioButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
    radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    radioButton.setChecked(true);
    radioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
    radioButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**

```
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setText("sattelite1");
        radioButton.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher), null, null, null);
        radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        radioButton.setChecked(true);
        radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding text to radio button you can do one thing, in a linear layout with horizontal orientation, add one textview first and the next to that add radio button with no text as below:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" text="button text" >
</TextView>
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_sattelite1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it to work with help of stackoverflow fellas :

```
radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 57, 72);
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.empty);
radioButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
```

so what is the R.drawable.empty ? This is a png file without background that you have to create it.

Thanks ....

Comment: No need to create empty image use `android.R.color.transparent` in that ButtonDrawable.